# How do you create multiple CSS files with Stylus?

Tags: css, ipad, node.js, stylus

I'm working on a application that will have a desktop/laptop web page component and a iPad component. Both components are from Node and Stylus. How can I create two CSS files from a single Stylus file, one for the desktop and one for iPad?

Comment: How would the compiler know which rules apply to which device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation you can use @import to use different files either css or stylus 
http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/docs/import.html